# Does LR automatically apply lens profiles?

Tags: lightroom

I am looking at buying a Nikon D810 with 20mm 1.8, 50mm 1.8, and 85mm 1.8. I use LR 5.7.1 and Windows 7.0. I found the files that LR stores its lens profiles in and all three lenses are listed there. My question is: After I upload a picture to LR, will LR automatically find the correct profile from the LR lens profile files and use it for corrections?

Answer (score 3):

No, not automatically. If you select to manually apply the lens correction, it will use the right one automatically - assuming it has the profile for that particular lens.

One option is to create a developer preset that applies the lens correction, and use this preset during the importing process. This way, all the imported photos will have the right lens correction applied, but nothing else.

Let me know if it's not clear enough and I'll try to take some screenshots of my setup ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Under basic if I check enable profile correction and then go to manual will that apply the correction? How could I create a developers preset and would that correct for all three lens?

Comment: No need to go to the Manual tab; when you select "enable profile correction" (under the basic tab) it will automatically select and apply the right profile (you can go to the Profile tab and confirm it selected the right combination of camera + lens).

To add a Preset, first apply the changes you want to save as a preset (in this case, only the profile correction) and then, on the Presets Panel (left side) click the + sign next to the word Preset and, on the popup screen, select only the Lens Correction option and save it (check it our here http://i.imgur.com/Wzu6Sh7.png)

Comment: Once the preset it's saved, when you are importing new photos, on the right side, in the "Apply During Import" menu, select the preset you just created under Develop Settings and the lens correction will be applied to all images you import, selecting the correct profile to every lens you used.